# Convert Query String to Request body response error

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to convert a working query string to a request body and I am receiving an error that I am missing an attribute. I received help from @Tanaike from another post that provided the encode URI function that breaks down the params into an encoded format. However, when I have 30-50 pairs in my "pairs" param, URLFetch has an error with the query string length limit. So I am trying to send it as a request body instead.

```
var botParams = {
"name": "TestBot",
"base_order_volume": 0.001,
"take_profit": 1.5,
"safety_order_volume": 0.001,
"martingale_volume_coefficient": 2,
"martingale_step_coefficient": 1,
"max_safety_orders": 1,
"active_safety_orders_count": 1,
"safety_order_step_percentage": 2.5,
"take_profit_type": "total",
"stop_loss_percentage": 0,
"cooldown": 0,
"pairs": [
  "BTC_ADA",
  "BTC_TRX"
],
"trailing_enabled":"true",
"trailing_deviation":0.5,
"strategy_list": [
  {
    "strategy":"cqs_telegram"
  }
]
  };    
  
  try {

//    var totalParams = keys.reduce(function(q, e, i) {
//      q += (e == "pairs" ? botParams[e].reduce(function(s, f, j) {
//        s += e + "[]=" + f + (j != botParams[e].length - 1 ? "&" : "");
//        return s;
//      },"") : e + "=" + (typeof botParams[e] == "object" ? 
//encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(botParams[e])) : 
//encodeURIComponent(botParams[e]))) + (i != keys.length - 1 ? "&" : "");
//      return q;
//    }, endPoint); //Thanks to Tanaike


//Call
//Base
var baseUrl = "https://3commas.io";        
//Total Endpoint
var endPoint = "/public/api/ver1/bots/274339/update?";


//Convert Bot Params + endPoint to Encoded URI
var keys = Object.keys(botParams);
var totalParams = keys.reduce(function(q, e, i) {
  q += e + "=" + (typeof botParams[e] == "object" ? encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(botParams[e])) : encodeURIComponent(botParams[e])) + (i != keys.length - 1 ? "&" : "");
  Logger.log(encodeURIComponent(botParams[e]))
  return q;
},endPoint);

Logger.log(totalParams)   

//Create Signature
var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(totalParams, secret);    
//Convert from byte
signature = signature.map(function(e) {return ("0" + (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16)).slice(-2)}).join("");

var headers = {
  "APIKEY": key,
  "Signature": signature,
};
var params = {
  "method": "PATCH",
  "headers": headers,     
  "payload" : totalParams,
  //Show full exceptions      
   muteHttpExceptions: true
};  

var finalURL = baseUrl + "/public/api/ver1/bots/274339/update";

Logger.log(finalURL)
//https://3commas.io/public/api/ver1/bots/274339/update

// Call final URL with params
var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(finalURL, params).getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(data);
Logger.log(json)
  } catch (err) {Logger.log(err)}
}
```

The current error I am receiving is `{error_attributes={name=[is missing]}, error_description=Invalid parameters, error=record_invalid}` So for some reason it's not recognizing my name attribute. When I logged the results I see the name is passed as a string.

Logged results: `/public/api/ver1/bots/274339/update?name=TestBot&base_order_volume=0.001&take_profit=1.5&safety_order_volume=0.001&martingale_volume_coefficient=2&martingale_step_coefficient=1&max_safety_orders=1&active_safety_orders_count=1&safety_order_step_percentage=2.5&take_profit_type=total&stop_loss_percentage=0&cooldown=0&pairs=%5B%22BTC_ADA%22%2C%22BTC_TRX%22%5D&trailing_enabled=true&trailing_deviation=0.5&strategy_list=%5B%7B%22strategy%22%3A%22cqs_telegram%22%7D%5D`

3commas docs: https://github.com/3commas-io/3commas-official-api-docs/blob/master/bots_api.md#edit-bot-permission-bots_write-security-signed

Just looking for suggestions as to what it could be. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out the issue. It was an encoding problem as suspected. Here's what ended up working.

```
        var totalParams2 = keys.reduce(function(q, e, i) {
          q += (e == "pairs" ? botParams[e].reduce(function(s, f, j) {
            s += e + encodeURIComponent("[]")+"=" + f + (j != botParams[e].length - 1 ? "&" : "");            
            return s;
          },"") : e + "=" + (typeof botParams[e] == "object" ? encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(botParams[e])) : encodeURIComponent(botParams[e]))) + (i != keys.length - 1 ? "&" : "");
          return q;
        }, "");
```

The addition of `e + encodeURIComponent("[]")+` specifically because of the way the API is setup. I had to encode my pairs array.

Comment: I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you for posting the answer. Upvoted this. And I apologize I couldn't help.

Comment: HI. I know this a REALLY old post but I'm wanting to this exact thing. When I put the snippet above in place the totalParams population in script below I get a signature invalid error.  I would really appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

I think that in your case, `botParams` might be required to send as form, while the query parameters are required to be created from `botParams` for creating the signature. So the modified script is as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
var key = 'apikey';
var secret = 'apisecret';
var editBots = "/ver1/bots/274339/update";
var baseUrl = "https://3commas.io";
var endPoint = "/public/api"+editBots;
var botParams = {
  "name": "TestBot",
  "base_order_volume": 0.001,
  "take_profit": 1.5,
  "safety_order_volume": 0.001,
  "martingale_volume_coefficient": 2,
  "martingale_step_coefficient": 1,
  "max_safety_orders": 1,
  "active_safety_orders_count": 1,
  "safety_order_step_percentage": 2.5,
  "take_profit_type": "total",
  "stop_loss_percentage": 0,
  "cooldown": 0,
  "pairs": ["BTC_ADA", "BTC_TRX"],
  "trailing_enabled": "true",
  "trailing_deviation": 0.5,
  "strategy_list": [{"strategy": "cqs_telegram"}]
};
var keys = Object.keys(botParams);
var totalParams = keys.reduce(function(q, e, i) {return q += (e == "pairs" ? botParams[e].reduce(function(s, f, j) {return s += e + "=" + f + (j != botParams[e].length - 1 ? "&" : "")},"") : e + "=" + (typeof botParams[e] == "object" ? encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(botParams[e])) : encodeURIComponent(botParams[e]))) + (i != keys.length - 1 ? "&" : "")}, endPoint + "?");
var signature = Utilities.computeHmacSha256Signature(totalParams, secret);
signature = signature.map(function(e) {return ("0" + (e < 0 ? e + 256 : e).toString(16)).slice(-2)}).join("");
var headers = {
  'APIKEY': key,
  'Signature': signature,
};
var params = {
  method: 'PATCH',
  headers: headers,
  payload: Object.keys(botParams).reduce(function(o, e) {
    o[e] = typeof botParams[e] == "object" ? JSON.stringify(botParams[e]) : e;
    return o;
  }, {}),
  muteHttpExceptions: true
};
var data = UrlFetchApp.fetch(baseUrl + endPoint, params).getContentText();
Logger.log(data)
```

#### Note:

- I'm not sure about the specification of the API. So if above script didn't work, can you ask the following points to the manager of API?

  1. About `"pairs": ["BTC_ADA", "BTC_TRX"],` of `botParams`, in this script, the same process with creating the query parameter is used like `pairs=BTC_ADA&pairs=BTC_TRX`. Is this correct?
  2. Are `key` and `secret` required to be included in `botParams` for creating `signature`?
  3. Are `key` and `secret` required to be included in the payload?
  4. Are above both 2 and 3 required?

### Edit:

#### Modification point:

From:

```
  payload: Object.keys(botParams).reduce(function(o, e) {
    o[e] = typeof botParams[e] == "object" ? JSON.stringify(botParams[e]) : e;
    return o;
  }, {}),
```

To:

```
  payload: Object.keys(botParams).reduce(function(o, e) {
    o[e] = typeof botParams[e] == "object" ? JSON.stringify(botParams[e]) : botParams[e];
    return o;
  }, {}),
```

Comment: @Phil I'm sorry. I cannot understand about ``chat`` you are saying.

Comment: @Phil Thank you for replying. I think that your replying information is important. From your comment, can you try the script as ``"pairs": ["BTC_ADA", "BTC_TRX"]`` in ``botParams``? By the way, can ``"pairs": ["BTC_ADA", "BTC_TRX"]`` be used for creating both the signature and the request body?

Comment: @Phil Thanks. I will check it.

Comment: @Phil I added a modification point. Could you please confirm it and try it. If the error related to ``signature`` occurs, can you ask about the correct value to the manager of API?

Comment: @Phil From the result before, it has already been found that the script for encrypting is correct. But in this situation, although the correct value is used for encrypting, the signature error occurs. Unfortunately, I cannot understand about the issue. If I found the issue, I would like to report here. But now, I have to apologize for my poor skill.

Comment: Thank you for trying. I'll accept it for the help given.

Comment: @Phil Thank you for replying. If you got more information from the manager and if you can provide the information, I would like to reflect to the script.

Comment: HI.  I know this a REALLY old post but I'm wanting to this exact thing.

Did anyone manage to get the script working when passing the values in the payload?

Comment: @Steve Unfortunately, I cannot test this script. But from the discussions with OP of this question, it seems that OP could confirm that the script worked. In that case, it seems that the important key point was the value of `pair`. But, I'm not sure whether this can be used for the current situation. It is required to test the script. I apologize for this.